# How to add -moz-transform to the style of an element

Tags: javascript, css

I want to add a transform to a specific element. I have some code that will append the correct prefect depending of the browser.

In chrome it works fine, but it firefox it doesn't work. when i do style['transform'] = "..." it works but when i do style['-moz-transform'] it doesn"t work.

So how do you use prefixes in firefox?

Comment: You've mis-spelled 'transform'

Answer (score 1):

the property names are: `WebkitTransform, MozTransform, msTransform and OTransform`.

You can check which property to use with this code:

```
function getTransformProperty(element) {
    var properties = ['transform', 'WebkitTransform',
                      'MozTransform', 'msTransform',
                      'OTransform'];
    var p;
    while (p = properties.shift()) {
        if (element.style[p] !== undefined) {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```